# laravel jestream - why i can't see the new logo, that i changed

Tags: image, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I have a problem in my laravel jetstream(livewire) /views/vendor/jetsream components, the logo( in auth-card-logo. blade , app-logo.blade) is not loading.

I have already published the Livewire stack's Blade components in order to change the logo but it doesn't seem working well.

I can only see the alt="..." attribute of <img..>, so i changed the logo in the "right" way, and I have really tried everything. I’ve tried the path to the image, its format and I don't have any idea on what is going on.

[image: This is what i see in my login]

```
authentication-card-logo.blade.php
resources › views › vendor › jetstream› components › authentication-card-logo.blade.php › img
<img src="{{ asset ('/images/voci_logo.jpeg') }}" alt="Logo" style="width: 40px">
```

[image: This is my auth-card-logo-blade component]

Comment: Try using a relative path (i.e. remove the leading `/`) like: images/voci_logo.jpeg. Then if that does not work, check if the image is really present and the path is correct (jpg vs jpeg, uppercase vs lowercase). Then if that does not work either the image is in the wrong location, let me know where you put that image in your filesystem.

Comment: I didn't get any  error, just the alt attribute of <img> tag. I posted the solutions that worked for me ,anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @posixpascal your filesystem idea made me think about the assets path, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your support; I solved it by putting the file in the assets folder, which seems to be the default folder for this change.

I also changed the path to : `src="{{ asset('/assets/images/my_logo.jpeg') }}` and now it's working.